# React canvas square grid not returning the correct square when clicked on. Starting board for an isometric game

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I have created a 10 x 10 grid and given them all an id.
There seems to be an issue using React useState with this canvas code, so i have had to add a few vars though the code to update it.

So my code should find the square thats length and width are equal to or greater than their starting position and less than their size.
However the first of the array doesnt event respond. When i have the size set correctly.

I will usually get 4 blocks being returned for once square.
When clicked on the square will turn red. However some only work when clicked on twice. and some insist i click another one first.
There is also an issue that when i try and move the grid to the center of the canvas. The first row shifts down more than it should.
It must be a silly maths error somewhere in here

This is going to be the base for a isometric city game. So i am trying to get the basic as solid as possible before i go on.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function GameCanvasContainer() {
  // Starting Title Size
  const [startingTileNumber, setStartingTileNumber] = useState({
    y: 10,
    x: 10,
  });
  const [tileSize, setTileSize] = useState({
    y: 40,
    x: 40,
  });
  const [startingTilePosition, setStartingTilePosition] = useState({
    xpos: 0,
    ypos: 0,
  });

  const [tileArray, setTileArray] = useState([]);
  const [totalUnlockedTiles, setTotalUnlockedTiles] = useState(0);
  const [tileIdNumber, setTileIdNumber] = useState(1);

  console.log('totalUnlockedTiles', totalUnlockedTiles);
  console.log('startingTilePosition', startingTilePosition);
  console.log('tileArray', tileArray);

  const useScript = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      let canvasBgColour = `#00f000`;

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const container = document.querySelector('#game-container');
      // canvas.style = "position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto; border:2px solid blue";
      container.appendChild(canvas);

      // Set size of canvas based on it parent
      var rect = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
      canvas.width = rect.width;
      canvas.height = rect.height;

      // Draw canvas
      context.fillStyle = canvasBgColour;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      // Mouse size
      let mouse = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        radius: (canvas.height / 90) * (canvas.width / 90),
      };

      // Mouse position
      container.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        mouse.x = e.x;
        mouse.y = e.y;
      });

      // Listen for clicks
      canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
      });

      class Tile {
        constructor(id, xpos, ypos, xsize, ysize, colour) {
          this.id = id;
          this.xpos = xpos;
          this.ypos = ypos;
          this.xsize = xsize;
          this.ysize = ysize;
          this.colour = colour;
        }

        draw(context) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.fillStyle = this.colour;
          context.fillRect(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.xsize, this.ysize);
          context.fillStyle = this.colour;
          context.strokeRect(this.xpos, this.ypos, this.xsize, this.ysize);
          context.stroke();
        }

        update() {
          console.log('update');
          this.colour = 'red'
          this.draw(context);
        }
      }

      let tiles = [];

      function createTileArray(context) {
        console.log('createTileArray');
        let dx = startingTilePosition.xpos;
        let dy = startingTilePosition.ypos;
        let id = tileIdNumber;

        for (var y = 0; y < startingTileNumber.y; y++) {
          for (var x = 0; x < startingTileNumber.x; x++) {
            const newTile = new Tile(id, dx, dy, tileSize.x, tileSize.y, 'white');
            dy += 40;
            id++;
            newTile.draw(context);
            tiles.push(newTile);
          }
          dy = 0;
          dx += 40;
        }

        setTileArray(tiles);
      }
// Main bit listening for clicks
      canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log('tileArr', tiles);

        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;

        console.log('mouse.x', x);
        console.log('mouse.y', y);

        tiles.forEach(function (tile, index) {
          
          if ((x < (tile.xpos + 40) && x >= tile.xpos) && (y < (tile.ypos + 40) && y >= tile.ypos)) {
            tile.update()
          }
        });
      });

      function run(context) {
        createTileArray(context);
      }

      run(context);
    }, []);
  };

  return (
    <div id='game-container' className='grid absolute w-full h-full'>
      {useScript()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default GameCanvasContainer;
```